# Deselect prefab child object after new selected (same prefab) child object is clicked on in Unity3D?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, highlight, gameobject, deselect

I have a prefab object that has many children. I highlight any "One" of these children and change its color. I am selecting another child of the same prefab and highlight it by changing its color but at the same time I want the previous child to deselect or change back to its original color.
The highlight and change color are not the problem, I am struggling to see if I need to store the children in an array and then loop through the objects to see if they have been selected and if so then change back or... this is where I am stuck. Any ideas, tips, recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/826999/deselect-object-when-another-instance-is-selected.html)!
This link helped, I had everything in the OnMouseDown checking but never updating. So, if anyone checks this out it could help with the same question I posted.